# how to return last row in specific sum?

Tags: mysql, sum

imagine we have 1 row which is students that contain, id, name, marks and rank. write query that return the last name of student where marks is equal to 100 ordered by grade.
example

---

```
 - id | name | marks | grade |
 - 01 | Jeff | 40    | 1 |
 - 02 | Annie| 40    | 3 |
 - 03 | Ramy | 20    | 5 |
 - 04 | Jenny| 20    | 2 |
```

so the result should return

> Annie

because Annie is the last row of the sum of marks where marks is equal to 100. Jeff is the first cause based on grade he's equal to 1 so he should be entered first, second is Jenny and third is Annie. Jeff(40)+Jenny(20)+Annie(40) = 100

Comment: Which MySQL version? `SELECT VERSION()`.. Because this is eazier to do in MySQL 8.0

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I believe you are hinting window functions.

Comment: "I believe you are hinting window functions" Yes with a window function @AnkitBajpai

Answer (score 1):

You can make a running sum MySQL's user variable. 
This query should work from MySQL 5.1 and up.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 Table1_alias.name
FROM (

  SELECT 
      Table1.name
   , (@running_marks_sum := @running_marks_sum + Table1.marks) AS running_marks_sum
  FROM 
   Table1
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @running_marks_sum := 0) AS init_user_param
  ORDER BY 
    Table1.grade ASC  
) AS Table1_alias
WHERE 
 Table1_alias.running_marks_sum = 100
```

**Result**

```
| name  |
| ----- |
| Annie |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

MySQL 8.0+ only

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 Table1_alias.name
FROM (

  SELECT 
     Table1.name
   , SUM(Table1.marks) OVER(ORDER BY Table1.grade) AS running_marks_sum
  FROM 
    Table1

) AS Table1_alias 
WHERE 
  Table1_alias.running_marks_sum = 100;
```

**Result**

```
| name  |
| ----- |
| Annie |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/26ZDczExMaMpjrwoHUWXP4/0)

Answer (score 0):

Keep the cumulative sum of `marks` to a variable. And use this as a sub-query and select the row having the `total` is 100. But if no row having the cumulative total as 100, then wont't get any result.

**Query**

```
set @total := 0;
select `id`, `name`, `marks`, `grade` from(
    select `id`, `name`, `marks`, `grade`, (@total := @total + `marks`) as `total`
    from `your_table_name`
    order by `grade`
) as `t`
where `t`.`total` = 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the database structure above, Below is one of the way to get the output

select name from (select * from (SELECT id,name,grade,marks, @total := @total + marks AS total FROM (stud, (select @total := 0) t) order by grade ) t WHERE total <=100 ) final_view order by grade desc limit 1